# Accessing property with different ways gives different results

Tags: python, properties

I have a `PropertyGroup` with let's say a property called `prop`.

I set `prop` like this:

```
propGroup['prop'] = something
```

and then access it like this:

```
propGroup.prop
```

If `prop` is a `StringProperty` is gives me the original value, but with an `IntProperty` or `FloatProperty` it gives me always 0.

And I tested reading the property with `propGroup['prop']`, it works so it's not type or affectation problem (I think).

I'm using Blender 2.78.5.

**[EDIT]**

After some research I understand now that the subscription accessing (`propGroup['prop']`) is for custom ID properties.

So now my question is: is there a way to access a non custom property (defined with `propGroup.prop = IntProperty()`) automatically with the name string name of the property?

I have a `str` which contains `'prop'` and I want to access `propGroup.prop`.

**[EDIT 2]**

Obviously it's not clear in my mind!

I read again this page: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties and I don't understand well the difference between dynamic and non-dynamic custom properties.

So in my case I have a property group where I defined non dynamic custom properties (like this `propGroup.prop = IntProperty()`) and I want to access it with a string variable.

It works with `StringProperty` but not with `IntProperty` or `FloatProperty`. So I'm confused. Do you know if this behaviour is normal with the blender API?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  An old but good blender [wiki about props](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties).   and [from the manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html)

Comment: Yes thank you I read several times the wiki, but as you see, things remain mysterious for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem. I used `setattr` and it works. Sorry for the non-clearness of all this :-).